# How to query wordpress page content with title

Tags: wordpress

I got  a code snippet which will echo the content of  a specific page,

```
$id = 123;
$post = get_page($id);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
echo $content;
```

How can I insert h1 title tag of specified page?

Comment: `How can i insert h1 title tag of specified page? Please help.` Could you be more precise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understood your question. If you are looking to display the post title within h1 tags, try this:

```
<?php
$id=123;
$post = get_page($id);
echo '<h1>' . $post->post_title . '</h1>
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   echo '<pre>';
   $page_id = 107;
   $page_data = get_page( $page_id );
   echo '<h3>'. $page_data->post_title .'</h3>';
   echo apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content); 
 ?>
```